# Configure Auth on Startup not working (OWIN) ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, owin

I have a simple asp.net MVC application with an account controller with 2 action methods to sign in and sign out.

My project has a custom _layout.cshtml from a theme we bought, but the server side logic was done based on this post:
http://www.andrewconnell.com/azure-ad-asp-net-mvc-walk-through-implementing-adal-owin

If I put a breakoint on the AuthorizationCodeReceived in ConfigureAUth, this breakpoint is never hit.

The azure SIGN IN Page is being shown when I click SIGN IN, but when it returns it doesnt show the Loginpartial view options where it says ITS AUTHENTICATED.

So my conclussion it goes to azure aad, user enters email and password, its "authenticated", then it goes back to the app but it says its not authenticated.

Very weird.

SO I will paste the most important parts of the code.

```
 public partial class Startup
    {
        // The Client ID is used by the application to uniquely identify itself to Azure AD.
        // The App Key is a credential used to authenticate the application to Azure AD.  Azure AD supports password and certificate credentials.
        // The Metadata Address is used by the application to retrieve the signing keys used by Azure AD.
        // The AAD Instance is the instance of Azure, for example public Azure or Azure China.
        // The Authority is the sign-in URL of the tenant.
        // The Post Logout Redirect Uri is the URL where the user will be redirected after they sign out.
        // This is the resource ID of the AAD Graph API.  We'll need this to request a token to call the Graph API.
        public static readonly string Authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, SettingsHelper.AADInstance, SettingsHelper.Tenant);

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = SettingsHelper.ClientId,
                    Authority = Authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = SettingsHelper.PostLogoutRedirectUri,

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                            var code = context.Code;
                            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.AppKey);
                            string userObjectId = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                            EfAdalTokenCache sampleCache = new EfAdalTokenCache(userObjectId);
                            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, sampleCache);
                            AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, SettingsHelper.GraphResourceId);
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },
                        AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                        {
                            context.HandleResponse();
                            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

The login partial, should show something like, Hello user! but it doesnt.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {

    <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle count-info" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                @*@{ Html.RenderAction("GetModules", "Module"); }*@
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            @Session["DateAndTime"].ToString()
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sign out", "SignOut", "Account")</li>
    </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sign in", "SignIn", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

The account controller

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public void SignIn()
        {
            // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }
        public void SignOut()
        {
            // Remove all cache entries for this user and send an OpenID Connect sign-out request.
            //string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
            //AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.Authority, new EfAdalTokenCache(userObjectID));
            //authContext.TokenCache.Clear();

            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }
```

and home controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //UserProfile up = Cache.GetUserProfile(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().Name);
            ViewData["SubTitle"] = "Welcome in ASP.NET MVC 5 INSPINIA SeedProject ";
            ViewData["Message"] = "It is an application skeleton for a typical MVC 5 project. You can use it to quickly bootstrap your webapp projects.";
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Minor()
        {
            ViewData["SubTitle"] = "Simple example of second view";
            ViewData["Message"] = "Data are passing to view by ViewData from controller";
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Update 1:
When I go to:
https://localhost:44300/

And Click on the Sign In link

It goes to: 
https://localhost:44300/Account/SignIn sometimes, and some other times it goes to Azure, when it returns from Azure it returns to: https://localhost:44300/Account/SignIn instead of https://localhost:44300/

but the SignIn breakpoint is never hit on the account controller!

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am facing something similar.